# Make new git branch track same remote branch

Tags: git

Is there a way to have a new branch automatically track the same remote as the existing branch it was created from?

Say I have a local branch `foo` that tracks a remote `origin/bar`. I can explicitly have a new branch `baz` based on `foo` also track `origin/bar` by doing:

```
git checkout foo
git checkout -b baz origin/bar
```

But is there a generic way to create the branch `baz` from `foo` and have it track the same remote as `foo` regardless of what that remote happens to be?

Comment: I think you can create a new branch and rebase from upstream like the one I did on this page: https://note.tianhaoz.com/git-tricks/add-branch-from-upstream.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But is there a generic way to create the branch `baz` from `foo` and have it track the same remote as `foo` regardless of what that remote happens to be?

Yes, but it's a little complicated.  Git being what it is, there are about twelve dozen<sup>1</sup> different ways to do this, but we'll just pick one here.

First, let's look at all the important *parts* of this:

- There are your own local branch names, `foo` and `baz` in your example.
- There are remote-tracking names such as `origin/bar` (full name `refs/remotes/origin/bar`).
- There's the commit hash ID to which each branch name or remote-tracking name points.
- And, there's an optional *upstream setting* for any (local) branch name.  Typically the upstream of some local branch is a remote-tracking name (Git calls this a "remote-tracking branch") using the same base name but prefixed with a remote name.  For instance, `master` typically has `origin/master` set as its upstream.  However, as in your example, the upstream of a branch need not match: the upstream of `foo` can be `origin/bar`.

  (It's also possible to set a *local* branch as the upstream of another local branch; this behaves the way you would expect.  Internally this is implemented by setting the `remote` half of the two-part upstream setting to `.`, which means your own repository.  But we get to ignore these details here.)

As [fphillipe mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56156670/1256452), we have `git branch --set-upstream-to`, which can set the upstream of any branch, at any time.  If there is already some upstream set, this replaces it.  If there was no upstream set, now there is.

We also have two different ways to create a new branch name:

- `git branch name [start-point]` creates the new (local) branch named *`name`*.  The initial hash ID stored in this name is given by *`start-point`*; if you omit *`start-point`*, the initial hash ID is whatever `git rev-parse HEAD` produces.
- `git checkout -b name [start-point]` creates the new (local) branch named *`name`* and then does a `git checkout` of that name, all in one.  It's essentially equivalent to running `git branch` followed by `git checkout`.

---

<sup>1</sup>["Ew, gross"](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross_(unit))

---

#### The goal

In this case, you want to create a local branch named `baz`, set its *hash* to match that of `foo`, and set its upstream to `foo`'s upstream, which is `origin/bar`.  That is, after creating `baz` you would like:

```
git rev-parse baz
```

to produce the same output as:

```
git rev-parse foo
```

—that means the same commit is the tip commit of each branch—but you want:

```
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name baz@{upstream}
```

to produce `refs/remotes/origin/bar`.

Both of the creation commands can, but don't always, also set the upstream of the newly created branch.  You can use the `--track` argument to force them to set it, and you can use the `--no-track` argument to force them not to set it.  The `--track` flag takes the remote-tracking name to use, so if you first figure out that the upstream of `foo` is `origin/bar`, you can write:

```
git checkout -b baz origin/bar
```

(or the same with `git branch` if you don't want to also check out the new branch).  But this has *two* bugs:

- It requires that you manually find the upstream of `foo`.  You want to automate this.
- Perhaps more important, it creates `baz` pointing to the same commit as `origin/bar`.  If `foo` points to a *different* commit, that violates one of the desires.

Hence the job must be done in several parts.  First, you will create the branch (and maybe switch to it if you like), using the local name `foo` to set the starting-point.  Both `git branch` and `git checkout` will *not* set the upstream of the new branch in this case, at least by default, but you can be totally explicit by using `--no-track`, or you can turn `foo` into a raw hash ID.  Usually all of this is unnecessary,<sup>2</sup> but if you wanted to go for raw hash ID, here's a shell fragment to do it:

```
name=baz
start=foo

hash=$(git rev-parse ${start}^{commit}) || exit
```

If `git rev-parse` fails to parse `foo` to a raw hash ID, or `foo` does not identify a commit, `git rev-parse` will produce an error message to stderr and exit nonzero, and the `|| exit` will have your shell fragment quit at this point.

Then:

```
git branch $name $hash || exit
```

will try to create the branch name `$name`, pointing to the desired hash.

We also need to find the upstream name, for which `git rev-parse` is again the command to use:

```
upstream=$(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name ${start}@{upstream}) || exit
```

As before, we have our shell fragment quit if `git rev-parse` has failed, letting `git rev-parse` print the appropriate error.  Now that we have the upstream, we can set it using `git branch --set-upstream-to`:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to $name $upstream
```

---

<sup>2</sup>At the command line, you just run a command and observe: if it did what you want, fine, if not, you correct as you go.  From a *script*, however, it's often hard to see what did or might happen.  It tends to be best to use something that has as few side-effects as possible.  So we break down each Git command into direct plumbing commands when possible.  I don't carry this to its extreme, in this example, as that gets too annoying, but I will show the `git rev-parse` operations.

---

#### The code

Putting the pieces together in the right order, plus a little bit of argument checking and use of `-e` to avoid all the `|| exit`s, gets us a full (but completely untested) shell script:

```
#! /bin/sh -e

usage() {
    echo "usage: $0 branch-name start-point"
}

case "$#" in
2) ;;
*) usage 1>&2; exit 1;;
esac

name="$1"
start="$2"
hash=$(git rev-parse ${start}^{commit})
upstream=$(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name ${start}@{upstream})
git branch $name $hash
git branch --set-upstream-to $name $upstream
```

After testing this, write it as an executable shell script somewhere in your `$PATH`, calling it (e.g.) `git-branch-with-upstream`, and then:

```
git branch-with-upstream baz foo
```

will invoke the script, which will create `baz` pointing to the same commit as `foo` and having `foo`'s upstream as `baz`'s upstream.

You now know how to write new Git commands!

Comment: Upvoted as the explanation looks pretty comprehensive explaining _why_ it works by detailing the git internals behind the answer. I will select it as the chosen answer once I test it out, assuming it does work.

Comment: This worked. Marked answer as accepted. Useful bits from this answer that I used in my final solution were 1) fetching the upstream using the rev-parse command which I hadn't been familiar with before, and 2) the clever hack where a script on the path named `git-do-something` can be executed as the git command `git do-something`.

Answer (score 2):

This is now (2022, 3 years later) supported.

With Git 2.35 (Q1 2022), `git -c branch.autosetupmerge=inherit branch new old` makes `new` to have the **same upstream as** the `old` branch, instead of marking "`old`" itself as its upstream.

Same for:

```
git switch --track=inherit -c new old
```

See [commit 44f14a9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/44f14a9d24cd9f04a0a789e58968d52d44d7f332), [commit d311566](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d3115660b4cc4b1a32e77ddfd289afde5e4b94d8), [commit a3f40ec](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a3f40ec4b0dc56a54e6a6866d0a44a04d4a6edf0) (20 Dec 2021) by [Josh Steadmon (`steadmon`)](https://github.com/steadmon).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0669bdf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0669bdf4ebc095a2b26654292e1ff38245ccf88a), 10 Jan 2022)</sup>

> ### [`branch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d3115660b4cc4b1a32e77ddfd289afde5e4b94d8): add flags and config to inherit tracking
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Josh Steadmon</sup>

> It can be helpful when creating a new branch to use the existing tracking configuration from the branch point.
> However, there is currently not a method to automatically do so.
>
> Teach `git-`{`branch`,`checkout`,`switch`} an "`inherit`" argument to the "`--track`" option.
> When this is set, creating a new branch will cause the tracking configuration to default to the configuration of the branch point, if set.
>
> For example, if branch "`main`" tracks "`origin/main`", and we run [`git checkout --track=inherit -b feature main`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d3115660b4cc4b1a32e77ddfd289afde5e4b94d8/Documentation/git-checkout.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout))</sup>, then branch "`feature`" will track "`origin/main`".
>
> Thus:
>
> - [`git status`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d3115660b4cc4b1a32e77ddfd289afde5e4b94d8/Documentation/git-status.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status))</sup> will show us how far ahead/behind we are from `origin`, and
> - [`git pull`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d3115660b4cc4b1a32e77ddfd289afde5e4b94d8/Documentation/git-pull.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull))</sup> will pull from `origin`.
>
> This is particularly useful when creating branches across many submodules, such as with [`git submodule foreach ...`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d3115660b4cc4b1a32e77ddfd289afde5e4b94d8/Documentation/git-submodule.txt#L206)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-foreach--recursiveltcommandgt))</sup> (or if running with a [patch such as this one](https://lore.kernel.org/git/20180927221603.148025-1-sbeller@google.com/), which we use at `$job`), as it avoids having to manually set tracking info for each submodule.
>
> Since we've added an argument to "`--track`", also add "`--track=direct`" as another way to explicitly get the original "`--track`" behavior ("`--track`" without an argument still works as well).
>
> Finally, teach `branch.autoSetupMerge` a new "inherit" option.
> When this is set, "`--track=inherit`" becomes the default behavior.

---

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d3115660b4cc4b1a32e77ddfd289afde5e4b94d8/Documentation/config/branch.txt#L10-L11):

> local branch or remote-tracking branch; `inherit` -- if the starting point
> has a tracking configuration, it is copied to the new

`git branch` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d3115660b4cc4b1a32e77ddfd289afde5e4b94d8/Documentation/git-branch.txt#L19):

> ```
> 'git branch' [--track [direct|inherit] | --no-track] [-f] <branchname> [<start-point>]
> ```

`git branch` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d3115660b4cc4b1a32e77ddfd289afde5e4b94d8/Documentation/git-branch.txt#L218-L223):

> The exact upstream branch is chosen depending on the optional argument:
>
> - `--track` or `--track direct` means to use the start-point branch itself as the
>   upstream;
> - `--track inherit` means to copy the upstream configuration of the
>   start-point branch.
>
> `--track direct` is the default when the start point is a remote-tracking branch.

`git branch` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d3115660b4cc4b1a32e77ddfd289afde5e4b94d8/Documentation/git-branch.txt#L227-L232):

> `start-point` is either a local or remote-tracking branch.
>
> Set it to `inherit` if you want to copy the tracking configuration from the branch point.
>
> See [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) and [`git config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for additional discussion on
> how the `branch.<name>.remote` and `branch.<name>.merge` options are used.

`git checkout` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d3115660b4cc4b1a32e77ddfd289afde5e4b94d8/Documentation/git-checkout.txt#L159):

> ### `--track [direct|inherit]`

`git switch` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d3115660b4cc4b1a32e77ddfd289afde5e4b94d8/Documentation/git-switch.txt#L155):

> ### `--track [direct|inherit]`

Comment: I guess that's better than what I just discovered, `git branch -u foo@{u}` sets the upstream to foo's upstream, it does all the machinations for you.

Comment: @jthill Yes, that is the idea indeed. Should be released early February.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `--set-upstream-to` of `git branch`:

```
git branch (--set-upstream-to=<upstream> | -u <upstream>) [<branchname>]
```

From the docs:

```
-u <upstream>, --set-upstream-to=<upstream>

Set up <branchname>'s tracking information so <upstream> is
considered <branchname>'s upstream branch. If no <branchname> is
specified, then it defaults to the current branch.
```

Answer (score 0):

To copy all of one branch's settings to another:

```
git config --local --get-regexp ^branch\\.$one \
| sed "s,^,git config ,;s,$one,$another," \
# | sh -x
```

To do it for just the `remote` and `merge` settings you could get more specific,

```
git config --local --get-regexp "^branch\\.$one\\.(remote|merge)"
```

I tend to do these things by constructing command lists as above, others might prefer

```
git config --local --get-regexp "^branch\\.$one\\.(remote|merge)" \
| while read config value; do
        git config ${config/.$one./.$another.} "$value"
  done
```